# Which distribution is suitable for the number of cars?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, poisson-distribution

> An economist wants to estimate the average number of cars per
> household in the country. Suppose that the actual data is as follows:
> 20% of the households do not have a car, 50% of the households have 1
> car, 20% of the households have 2 cars, 10% of the households have 3
> cars. For simplicity, the economist assumes in his model that no
> households have more than 3 cars.
>
> The economist plans to use the following procedure: randomly select
> 100 households and record the number of cars owned by each of them.
> Then take the average of these 100 numbers as an estimate of the
> required average number of cars per household.
>
> Suppose the economist obtains the following data: among 100 randomly
> selected households, 25 do not have a car, 52 have one car, 15 have 2
> cars, and 8 have 3 car».

What is the population distribution in this problem?
The values of random variables are discrete (so it can’t be Normal), the graph of the distribution is bell-shaped. It is definitely not Bernoulli, Binomial or Geometric. Could it be Poisson?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please review the [Meta Read](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and enhance your question to provide your motivation/attempts.

Comment: The population distribution appears to be what you said: *"the actual data is as follows: 20% of the households do not have a car, 50% of the households have 1 car, 20% of the households have 2 cars, 10% of the households have 3 cars"*.  That does not have to match any named distribution

Comment: I agree with @Henry. The specified dist'n is consistent with the data from 100 households according to `prop.test` in R: `prop.test(c(25,52,15,8),rep(100,4),c(.2,.5,.2,.1))$p.val`
returns large P-value $0.4438579.$ Not consistent with $\mathsf{Binom}(3, .4);$ For that `prop.test` gives P-val 0.009.